# SQL Server not running queries on remote (Linked MySQL) server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linked-server

For various horrible reasons, we've had to link SQL Server to a MySQL database using Linked Servers and an ODBC Data Source. The queries run fine, but looking at the query plans you can see that SQL Server is always doing a full table scan on the remote server - and then doing any joins/filtering at the SQL Server end.

How can we push these to the MySQL server instead?

Thanks

James

Comment: How are you actually running the queries? OpenQuery?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557285/forcing-a-sql-remote-query-to-filter-remotely-instead-of-locally/1559168#1559168

Comment: I was just running them directly - select * from mylinkedserver..tablename etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write your queries like this ...

```
select * from openquery
 ( myLinkedServer
  ,'Select * from mySQLTables where complicated joins/filters')
```

the joins/filters should happen remotely.