# How do I specify date literal when writing SQL query from SQL Server that is linked to Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, date-formatting

I have a SQL Server 12.0 database that is linked to an Oracle 12.1 database.

I want to create a view in the SQL Server database that returns data from an Oracle table filtered by date. The Oracle table has an index on the date column.

A query that works successfully is:

```
select * from ORADB..SCHEMA.MYTABLE where MYDATE >= '20140701';
```

However this runs very slowly. I assume it is because the comparison is taking place in SQL Server so every row is being returned.

If I go:

```
DECLARE @earliest date = '20140701';
select * from ORADB..SCHEMA.MYTABLE where MYDATE >= @earliest;
```

Then it runs fast, presumably because the condition is being passed to Oracle so the Oracle index on the table is being used.

My problem is that I want to create a view. I can't find a way of using the second version of the code to create a view. If I simply do:

```
create myview as select * from ORADB..SCHEMA.MYTABLE where MYDATE >= '20140701';
```

Then it runs slowly.

Is there another format for the date literal that SQL Server will pass to Oracle, or is there another solution? I wondered also if it was to do with the parameters used in creating the link to Oracle. For reference they are:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ORADB', @srvproduct=N'Oracle', @provider=N'OraOLEDB.Oracle', @datasrc=N'DPDB'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'ORADB',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'MYUSER',@rmtpassword='#######'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORADB', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORADB', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORADB', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORADB', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORADB', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORADB', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORADB', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORADB', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORADB', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORADB', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORADB', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORADB', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ORADB', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

EDIT: I just found a very similar question: [Forcing a SQL Remote Query to filter remotely instead of locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557285/forcing-a-sql-remote-query-to-filter-remotely-instead-of-locally)

Comment: Try ISO format `'2014-01-01'` YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Thanks @lad2025, I tried that but it still runs slow.

Comment: Since you can't create a view with a parameter, why not just create a function instead ? You can use it like a view, join it, AND have params.

Comment: Thanks @iDevlop, I was trying to keep things simple. That's probably my next approach. The other is to move the filtering of the view back into Oracle, but I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: The problem you have is not bound to the format of the date literal... You'll have to find a solution passing your date as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo. I'm much more familiar with Oracle than SQL Server. I was hoping that by telling SQL Server that it was a constant date and so it would pass the query straight to Oracle rather than performing WHERE clause in SQL Server.

Comment: I have no experience with this, but you could check the execution plan. Actually I do not think, that a date literal forces the full work load to be done row by row in the calling system...

Comment: Looking at the estimated execution plans of the two queries, the one with the variable is SELECT->Compute Scalar->Remote Query. The one with the literal is SELECT->Filter->Compute Scalar->Remote Query. The estimated cost and number of rows for the Remote Query is around 3 times for the literal.

Answer (score 38):

I prefer the ODBC format:

```
--DateTime
SELECT {ts'2015-09-20 12:30:00'}
--Time (however this comes with "today"-time)
SELECT {t'12:30:00'}
--Date
SELECT {d'2015-09-20'}
GO
```

The simple date literal is not culture independent...

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT CAST('2014-09-13' AS DATETIME);
GO
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT CAST('2014-09-13' AS DATETIME);--ERROR: there's no month "13"
GO
```

But it works - however - with target type `DATE` (this difference is rather weird...):

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT CAST('2014-09-13' AS DATE);
GO
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT CAST('2014-09-13' AS DATE);--works
GO
```

Thx to lad2025 I want to add for completness the "full" ISO 8601, which works fine:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT CAST('2014-09-13T12:30:00' AS DATETIME);
GO
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT CAST('2014-09-13T12:30:00' AS DATETIME);
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Shnugo. I've tried that but it doesn't solve my problem, still slow.

Comment: @Shungo Maybe I wasn't specific enough about ISO format [ISO 8601 Format](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) `The advantage in using the ISO 8601 format is that it is an international standard.  datetime values that are specified by using this format are unambiguous` And **`Also, this format is not affected by the SET DATEFORMAT or SET LANGUAGE settings.`** But you have to use full specification with time part.

Comment: @lad2025. You are rigth with implicit conversion, but just try the second code block. The cast throws an exception because the "13" ist taken as the month... Change the "13" to a smaller number and the cast will come back with two different dates...

Comment: I wasn't specific enough. Check with full datetime [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377710#resultSets). **`'2014-09-13T00:00:00'`** is culture independent. There is no error.

Comment: @lad2025, there's one more advantage. When I once checked the behaviour of a CTE I found, that the ODBC-literals are taken as DATE(TIME) values immediately, while an ISO literal is going through an implicit CAST. I could imagine, that the optimizer could use this knowledge in some cases...

Comment: @lad2025, OK, together with the "THH:MM:SS"-part it's working fine. But your comment states the "YYYY-MM-DD"-part only...

Comment: @Shnugo No problem, this was quick comment and I assumed that everyone knows ISO-8601 :)

Comment: There's a reason to prefer the ISO-8601 format - in SQL Server 2014 at least, the ODBC format does not work for dates outside of the range of the datatype datetime (i.e. dates prior to 1753-01-01) - I've got test code for this in another answer on this page. The ISO-8601 format supports the full range of values available in the datetime2 datatype, as far back as 0001-01-01, so it's a bit more robust in this way. 

Though I'll admit to never having to have handled dates before 1753 yet.

Comment: Important: ODBC-format literals are _not_ auto-parameterized. That's a serious issue in applications that dynamically generate 'ad-hoc' SQL statements with literals rather than parameters, running on a busy production server with 'forced parameterization' enabled. It results in query plan cache pollution, followed by increased CPU load and longer response times due to excessive query plan recompilations. [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175037(v=sql.105)). That document is about SQL2008, but a simple test proves SQL2017 has the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend using the full ISO 8601 format as suggested by @lad2025:

```
'2017-10-06T14:57:23'
```

This is superior to the ODBC format suggested by @Shnugo.

In SQL Server 2014 at least, the ODBC format will not work for dates prior to 1753-01-01 (e.g. those dates outside of the range of the old DATETIME data type), whereas the ISO 8601 format does.

To test this yourself, try the following queries:

```
--This will work
DECLARE @DateISO DATE = '0001-01-01T00:00:00';
SELECT @DateISO;

--This will also work
DECLARE @DatetimeISO DATETIME2 = '0001-01-01T00:00:00';
SELECT @DatetimeISO;

--This will not work
DECLARE @DateODBC DATE = {D '0001-01-01'};
SELECT @DateODBC;

--This will also not work
DECLARE @DatetimeODBC DATETIME2 = {ts '0001-01-01 00:00:00'};
SELECT @DatetimeODBC;
```

Even if you don't think the dates you're working with will ever be before the year 1753, it's a good habit to be in. I ran into this while looking at setting up a calendar table to reference in queries.

Answer (score 4):

If the query is running on Oracle database, then I suggest use the **ANSI** date literal which uses a fixed Format **YYYY-MM-DD**.

For example,

```
DATE '2015-10-20'
```

In Oracle, `'20140701'` is a **string** and not a **DATE**. You might just be lucky to see an **implicit data type conversion** and get the result based on the **locale-specific NLS settings of your client**. You should always avoid it, and **explicitly** convert the string into date for date comparisons.

Comment: Thanks Lalit, I understand that '20140701' is a string in Oracle. I can't use the syntax DATE '2015-10-20' as SQL Server doesn't understand it. That's what I'd use if I was writing the query directly in Oracle. I have tried a variety of date formats. All the advice I found on the net for date literals in SQL Server advised using 20140701 rather than 2014-07-01.

Comment: However (this is rather weird...) It is possible to cast and convert this to `DATE`, But if you cast or convert it to `DATETIME`, it is not culture independant... Try `SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT CAST('2015-10-20' AS DATE);` and then change this to `DATETIME`