# T-SQL not understand why gives error when using same datetime format with table in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Can someone please explain why CreatedDate column even has '2017-07-28 21:36:29.120' value, it gives error when using in where clause with same format which table has like below?

This give error. But this is same with data in table.

```
where CreatedDate <= '2017-07-28 21:36:29.120'
```

This is working. But this is not same format with table.

```
where CreatedDate <= '2017/28/07 21:36:29.120'
```

Comment: PSA: [ISO date format](https://xkcd.com/1179/). What database? (`tsql` is not specific.) What datatype is `CreatedDate`? What _error_? What [DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql)?

Comment: Datatype is datetime. It is working on my db just not working on source(client) db. `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the date format, which is `YMD` in one case and `YDM` in the second.

**You should *never* write a date literal in a culture depending format!**

This works on your machine, but will break on a customer's machine with different culture settings.

Find some details about implicit (language bound) settings here

```
SELECT * FROM sys.syslanguages;
```

You can use

```
SET DATEFORMAT xyz --details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql
```

Or

```
SET LANGUAGE xyz --Find supported languages with the statement above
```

But best - and **the only recommended!** - is:

**Use culture independant formats like `ODBC`or `ISO8601`!**

Read this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275965/5089204)
 and [one more related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33230070/5089204).

Comment: This is working : `SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
DECLARE @datevar datetime2 = '2017-07-27 15:54:40.000'
select top 1 * from TableName(NOLOCK) where CreatedDate <=  @datevar`. Also wıthout SET DATEFORMAT dmy it is again working. `DECLARE @datevar datetime2 = '2017-07-27 15:54:40.000
select top 1 * from TableName(NOLOCK) where CreatedDate <=  @datevar`. And I forgot to say in question. It is working when send query by SSIS just not working when directly run query in SQL. Not understand why, but your answer is working. Thanks