# Date conversion and culture: Difference between DATE and DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime, casting

I've written a lot of answers about `date` or `datetime` conversions from strings. Living in a german speaking country, I'm used to deal with *non-us_english* date formats and I'm used to use secure literals (I prefere the `ODBC` format) and I never use `CONVERT` without the third parameter. That is not the question and please do not provide answers in this direction...

Very often one can read, that a format `yyyy-mm-dd` is standard (ISO8601, ANSI, whatever) and therefore culture independant.

Today I had to edit [one of these older answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33230070/5089204), as I had stated there, that the observed behaviour is depending on something else.

The question is:

#### Why (if there is a reason) is there a difference between `DATE` and `DATETIME`?

... at least in my environmen, which is SQL Server 2014 (12.0.4237.0) at the moment.

I hope, this was not asked before...

Try this:

No problems here, `DATE` works as expected

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
DECLARE @dt DATE='2017-01-13'; 
SELECT @dt;
SELECT CAST('2017-01-13' AS DATE);
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'2017-01-13'); --no culture / format specified
GO
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
DECLARE @dt DATE='2017-01-13';
SELECT @dt;
SELECT CAST('2017-01-13' AS DATE);
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'2017-01-13');
```

But now check the same with `DATETIME`

```
--No problem here:
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
DECLARE @dt DATETIME='2017-01-13'; 
SELECT @dt;
SELECT CAST('2017-01-13' AS DATETIME);
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-01-13'); 
GO

--breaks, due to the "13" and would deliver a wrong result (even worse), if the "day" was not more than "12":
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
DECLARE @dt DATETIME='2017-01-13'; 
SELECT @dt;
SELECT CAST('2017-01-13' AS DATETIME);
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-01-13');
```

Is this a bug, purpose or just grubbiness?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ISO-8601 for `DATETIME` (the older type) is somehow "broken" or "adapted" (depending on whether you look at it as a bug or a feature) - you need to use `YYYYMMDD` (***without*** any dashes) to make it work irrespective of the language settings.

For `DATE` or the `DATETIME2(n)` datatypes, this has been fixed and the "proper" ISO-8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD` will always be interpreted correctly.

```
-- OK because of "adapted" ISO-8601
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
DECLARE @dt DATETIME='20170113'; 

SELECT @dt;

SELECT CAST('20170113' AS DATETIME);
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '20170113'); 

-- OK because of DATETIME2(n)
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
DECLARE @dt2 DATETIME2(0) = '2017-01-13'; 

SELECT @dt2;

SELECT CAST('2017-01-13' AS DATETIME2(0));
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), '2017-01-13');
```

It's a quirk of the `DATETIME` type (and not the only one....) - just register it, know about it - and move on (meaning: don't use `DATETIME` anymore - use `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` instead - much nicer to work with!) :-)

Comment: As I assumed this seems to be historical residue. Your statement *just register it, know about it - and move on (meaning: don't use DATETIME anymore - use DATE or DATETIME2(n) instead* is convincing :-D

Comment: @Shnugo: yes, it's most likely a legacy issue - we can probably even blame Sybase for the original screw up :-D

Comment: @LukStorms: **OH YES** there is! I get `Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Fehler beim Konvertieren einer Zeichenfolge in ein Datum und/oder eine Uhrzeit.` which translated basically means: error when converting a date and/or time stamp. The format *without* the `T` in the middle **DOES NOT WORK** for languages other than English - see Zohar's excellent response below

Comment: @LukStorms - You didn't get an error because of the date you used - Your day part is 12. Under the German language, SQL Server will convert it to December 1st 2017 - Try `SET LANGUAGE GERMAN; SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DateTime, '2017-01-12 00:00:00'));` The  Result is `Dezember` If your day part was 13, you would get an error - `Bei der Konvertierung eines varchar-Datentyps in einen datetime-Datentyp liegt der Wert außerhalb des gültigen Bereichs.` - I'm assuming the german version of `error converting varchar to datetime...`

Comment: @ZoharPeled: it says "Converting a varchar datatype into datetime resulted in a alue outside the valid range" - basically month no. 13 isn't defined :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for explaining the point I implicitly tried to make with that Sql. That the datetime format with a space before the time (instead of a T) isn't an ISO datetime format, and will be processed depending on the language.

Comment: @LukStorms - Yes. the ODBC canonical (120, 121) is not ISO8601 (126). I'm guessing marc should edit his answer to fix this mistake.

Answer (score 3):

(Started out as a comment, but...) To add some more data to marc_s's answer, `datetime` will also fail with `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss` - So

```
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
DECLARE @dateTimeFailes DATETIME ='2017-01-13 00:00:00';
```

Will result with the same error. However, Once you replace the space between the Date and Time parts with a `T`, SQL Server will suddenly understand the format -

```
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
DECLARE @dateTime DATETIME ='2017-01-13T00:00:00';
```

Will work as expected.

Here is a quick list of acceptable and unacceptable formats:

```
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
-- Correct 
DECLARE @date DATE ='2017-01-13';
DECLARE @dateTime DATETIME ='2017-01-13T00:00:00'; 
DECLARE @dateTimeDateOnly DATETIME ='20170113';

-- Incorrect
DECLARE @WrongFormatDateTime DATETIME ='2017-01-13 00:00:00'; 
DECLARE @WrongFormatDate DATETIME ='2017-01-13';
```

Comment: Absolutely right - that's the second ISO-8601 format that works for `DATETIME` regardless of language and regional settings - thanks for adding. And again: the `'2017-01-13 00:00:00'` will work **just fine** with `DATETIME2(n)` - one more reason to dump `DATETIME` ....-

Comment: @marc_s Thanks! I just remembered reading a blog post a few years back - You might want to add that link to your answer: [why you should never use datetime again](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnsoldevs/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/)