# Does SQL Server store DateTime Offset Agnostic?

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012

I've been searching all morning and can't seem to get a handle on this (though I do have a few possible theories).  It's also not impossible that this might be a duplicate but please take into account that all the questions I searched, didn't give a definitive answer but were rather too open to interpretation.

In SQL Server (>= 2012), a table column of type `datetime`, is it stored timezone offset agnostic or is how does it work?  From my investigation, it would seem that `datetimeoffset` is the type that includes the offset with the date/time while `datetime` simply omits this?

When I read the data from the database, and use `CONVERT( datetimeoffset, [My Column] )` it's giving me `2016-09-21 16:49:54.7170000 +00:00` while myself and the server are both in UTC +02:00 which reinforces my belief, am I correct?

What I'm trying to achieve, is allow data to be saved FROM various tz offsets (via a function), then saved into the database in UTC and finally convert the `datetime` value back to a (possibly different) offset.  I don't care about DST / etc as the users browser will give me the current offset at the time of the saving and the viewing user will give me their tz offset at the time of viewing.  For historic reports the exact time of day (DST dependent) is irrelevant.

Currently the database tables already use `datetime` as opposed to `datetimeoffset`; it's my observation that it's completely fine to continue with this, though at some point, it might be good to change to `datetimeoffset` in order to then have start recording the historic tz offset?

Any clarity will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Yes. the `DateTime` (and `DateTime2`) data type is not time-zone aware.

**The long version:**

Official documentation of [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clearly states that the `DateTime` data type does not support time zone (nor daylight savings time). Same is true for [`DateTime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

You can see in both pages there's a table that describes the data type's properties, and in that table, for both data types, the value for "Time zone offset aware and preservation" and for "Daylight saving aware" is "No".

> ```
> Time zone offset aware and preservation     No
> Daylight saving aware                       No
> ```

The description of `DateTime` is as follows:

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of day with fractional seconds that is based on a 24-hour clock.

The description of `DateTime2` is as follows:

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of day that is based on 24-hour clock.
>   **datetime2** can be considered as an extension of the existing datetime type that has a larger date range, a larger default fractional precision, and optional user-specified precision.

The only data type that is timezone aware is [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of a day that has time zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock.

Btw, it is recommended to choose `DateTime2` over `DateTime`, both by Microsoft official documentation:

> **Note**
>   Use the **time**, **date**, **datetime2** and **datetimeoffset** data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable. time, datetime2 and datetimeoffset provide more seconds precision. datetimeoffset provides time zone support for globally deployed applications.

And by SQL Server professionals: [Why You Should Never Use DATETIME Again!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnsoldevs/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/):

`Datetime` also have a bug/feature implicitly converting string literals of format `yyyy-mm-dd` / `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` - `Datetime` will try to convert them using local settings, while `Datetime2` will always convert them correctly. 
[Check out this SO post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792766/date-conversion-and-culture-difference-between-date-and-datetime).

Comment: This REALLY helps clarify the documentation, sometimes all you need is a bit of a different perspective, thanks!  What are the chances you're familiar on this same topic re C# and JavaScript/TypeScript?  I'm trying to ensure I properly understand all 3 while I'm doing this review.

Comment: I am working with c#, last time I've written javascript was probably 7 or 8 years ago, and I know nothing of TypeScript. I suggest posting relevant questions on stackoverflow - providing the questions are good, you should be getting good answers.

Comment: Thanks, I'm first going to do a bit more digging armed with my newly found clarity!  If I'm still stuck thereafter, I'll ask a question.

Comment: Glad to help :-)