# How to use varchar date field in between clause - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID -> int
Name -> varchar
Date -> varchar
```

I want to select values between two dates like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '10-12-2018' AND '11-12-2018';
```

but this query returns wrong values because I'm comparing to strings.

I already tried to cast the date row to date inside the query but it doesn't work.

I'm using SQL SERVER 2012.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be very helpful!

Comment: Use the right datatype for your data, and this isn't a problem. Change your column `[date]` to a `date`; why would you call a column "date" and it be a `varchar`..?

Comment: Is not because you're comparing strings, is because the date format is ambiguous. `10-12-2018` could be 12th of October **or** 10th of December, depending on the date format

Comment: The problem is that I cannot change! I already speaked with my boss and it's not possible to change!

Comment: @Remus it's definately the `varchar` datatype. Did you know that `'12-12-2000'` is "after" `'01-01-2020'`?

Comment: Why can't you change it? What was their reason? The problem is the choice of datatype.

Comment: the date we are using it's day-month-year

Comment: Give example input and output

Comment: @AlexandreCristo dates have no format. They are binary values, like ints, floats, decimals. Formats apply *ONLY* when you want to parse text into dates or format dates as text for display or export purposes. You just *can't* index the string format you specified. The expression you specified will never work *unless* you parse the string field *and* use proper date literals or parameters. If you parse the field though, you won't be able to use any indexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you "must" (there is no good reason why you can't) change the data type, you'll have to convert the value of your column. This is going to come at a **huge cost**, as your query will no longer be SARGable (this means that any indexes you have on `[DATE]` will **not** be used).

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date,[DATE],105) BETWEEN '20181210' AND '20181211';
--Note the unambiguous date format for the literal strings
```

I've used `TRY_CONVERT` as style 105 assumes all your dates are in the format `dd-MM-yyyy`, but won't cause an error if there are any that are invalid.

Alternatively, if you can, add a computed column and index it. you can add a persisted date column by doing:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD DateDate AS TRY_CONVERT(date,[DATE],105) PERSISTED;
```

Then (after adding your index(es)) you can query that column instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE DateDate BETWEEN '20181210' AND '20181211';
```

Comment: Just a side note - the `Date` data type will also handle correctly the more human-readable readable of the ISO8601 string format - `yyyy-mm-dd`. (The `DateTime` data type will not - [it will still depend on local settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792766/date-conversion-and-culture-difference-between-date-and-datetime)).

Comment: That's why I always prefer the `yyyyMMdd` format, @ZoharPeled. Regardless of data type and language settings, it is completely unambiguous.