# TSQL what is the difference between using dd-mm-yyyy and yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a rather basic question out of interest. In T-SQL (SSMS or the like), what is the difference, "behind the scenes", between using `dd-mm-yyyy` and `yyyy-mm-dd` in a where statement.

For example, these two queries give me different results

```
select * from DB..table where application_date > '01-01-2019' and application_date < '01-06-2019' order by app_ID;

select * from DB..table where application_date > '2019-01-01' and application_date < '2019-06-01' order by app_ID;
```

It seems that the first is a sub set of the second. 
For comparison, the first gives me 83 records, while the second gives me over 11 thousand with change.

It would be interesting to understand, if someone could enlighten me.

Comment: It depends a lot on what the data type of `application_date` is. Is it a `datetime` or a `varchar`?

Comment: But regardless you should get into the habit of using ISO format, `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid When working with `DateTime`, use `yyyyMMdd` for date only values. Read my answer for details.

Comment: Just when you I thought I’d seen the last of ODBC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal `'01-06-2019'` is actually interpreted to be `2019-01-06`, which is *not* the same thing as `2019-06-01`, which the second query is using.

You may read SQL Server's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#supported-string-literal-formats-for-datetime) covering supported date literal formats.  But in general, try to stick with ISO date formats, which are supported by pretty much every SQL database.  So, the second version of your query is the one you should always try to use.

Comment: In my experience the only format that is always interpreted correctly is `'20190601'` The ISO format with dashes (`'2019-06-01'`) does not always work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL is fairly lax, and the dashed version would work, but thanks for commenting.

Comment: Yes, if it's going to be converted to `datetime` rather than `datetime2` or other similar modern types, `nnnn-nn-nn` is unsafe. `set dateformat dmy
select MONTH(CONVERT(datetime,'1992-02-06'))` returns 6 still.

Comment: I was talking about SQL Server, not MySQL

Comment: In SQL Server there's a difference between the `DateTime` data type and `DateTime2` / `DateTimeOffset` / `Date` and `Time` data types with the dashed version of the ISO 8601 standard. The `DateTime` data type conversion depends on laugnage/dateformat settings for converting `yyyy-mm-dd` while the other data types will *always* convert it properly. Read [Date conversion and culture: Difference between DATE and DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792766/date-conversion-and-culture-difference-between-date-and-datetime) for more details.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you, that is nice and simple.  :)

Answer (score 6):

String representations of `datetime` values are culture dependent.
In USA, for instance, the string representation format is `MM/dd/yyyy`, while in UK it's `dd/MM/yyyy`.
This means that SQL Server will convert string literals to `datetime` based on the culture settings, specifically, it's [`DATEFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - Unless the string representation format complies to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard - which is either `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` or `yyyyMMddTHHmmss`.

However, there is a little known bug (or feature) with the `DateTime` data type, when converting date-only values from string formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd`, the conversion still depends on the culture settings - while converting from the alternate ISO 8601 format `yyyyMMdd` is perfectly safe for all datetime data types.

This is probably because this format is not unique to ISO 8601 - it's also a part of the ODBC canonical format - which is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` - almost the same as ISO 8601, just with a space instead of the T as a separator between the date part and the time part.

This bug only exists in the `DateTime` data type, and is one of several reasons why you should always prefer to work with the newer and improved `DateTime2` data type.

for more information, read [Date conversion and culture: Difference between DATE and DATETIME.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792766/date-conversion-and-culture-difference-between-date-and-datetime)

**TL;DR;**
The only safe string representation date format to work with `datetime` is `yyyyMMdd`.
all other formats conversions are culture dependent and might yield errors or worst - wrong results.

Main points:

- When you can, prefer `DateTime2` over `datetime`.
- When you can, prefer avoiding string representations of `datetime`.
- When you have to work with string representations of `datetime`, Always work with one of the ISO 8601 formats - either `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` or `yyyyMMddTHHmmss`
- When you have to work with `DateTime` and string representations of date only, **always** use `yyyyMMdd`.

Comment: thank you. A little technical... but interesting none the less. :)

Comment: Yeah, well, this is a technical business... Anyway, Glad to help :-)