# SQL Server. T-SQL select date field "BETWEEN" and "NOT IN"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2005

So I have a datetime field in SQL Server called 'dtJornada'

This query returns incorrect sintax. What would be the correct way of writing it?

```
select * from B
where dtJornada BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-04'
AND dtJornada NOT IN ['2018-01-01T14:25:10']
```

Comment: Use parentheses (`()`) not brackets(`[]`) for your `IN` list. But also, 2005 is long out of support, you should really be looking at upgrade paths.

Comment: Is the time important or do you just want to exclude a certain date?

Comment: Also, as 2005 doesn't support the `date` data type `BETWEEN` may not provide the results you're after. I would suggest `>=` and `<` logic.

Comment: As an example to my above comment, the date and time `'2018-01-04 00:00:00.003'` is **not** between `'2018-01-01'` and `'2018-01-04'`.

Comment: And since it's 2005 it also means no `DateTime2` data type - so beware of `yyyy-mm-dd` format, as it's culture dependent when using `DateTime`. Use `yyyymmdd` instead. For more information, [read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55275699/3094533)

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
dtJornada NOT IN ['2018-01-01T14:25:10']
```

The correct would be:

```
dtJornada NOT IN ('2018-01-01T14:25:10')
```

...although if you only want to filter out one value, why use `NOT IN`? You can just do:

```
dtJornada <>'2018-01-01T14:25:10'
```

Comment: Damm.. indeed what a shame!.. dunno why I had brackets in mind! sorry for that