# Conversion failed when converting date from character string

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to rearrange Invoice date field of YYYMMDD into short date format DD/MM/YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY UK/British format in a SELECT statement.

Performing on MSSQL server 2008 R2

**SQL**

```
CONVERT(date,CAST(columnvalue AS VARCHAR),103)
```

Produces YYYY-MM-DD

```
CAST(right(convert(varchar,columnvalue),2)+substring(convert(VARCHAR,columnvalue ),5,2) + left(convert(VARCHAR,columnvalue ),4)AS VARCHAR)
```

Produces DDMMYYY

```
CONVERT(date,CAST(right(convert(varchar,columnvalue),2)+substring(convert(VARCHAR,columnvalue),5,2) + left(convert(VARCHAR,columnvalue),4)AS VARCHAR),103)
```

**ERROR**

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Invoice date` data type is date or varchar?

Comment: It fails because you attempt to convert 'ddmmyyyy' into a date & that input format is not supported - it's interpreted as 'yyyymmdd'  - e.g. with mm == 20

Comment: What is the data type of `columnvalue`?

Answer (score 2):

The following will be helpful:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105) AS [DD-MM-YYYY]
```

Comment: Not helpful. GETDATE() retrieves current computer date and not Invoice date value in database table. Also, the AS [DD/MM/YYYY] just changes the column name title.

Comment: I gave `AS [DD/MM/YYYY]` for your understanding, you can place `AS [InvoiceDate]` or what ever you are required.  As I already asked in comment, what is the data type of invoice date and for which sample date it throw error?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data type of the column you are attempting to convert, there are different ways to solve this.

Assuming the column is already one of the date types (`date`/`datetime`/`datetime2`) the conversion is as simple as it gets - all you need is to choose the correct `style` parameter.

For British/French (`dd/mm/yyyy`) you use 103:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), dateOrdateTimeValue, 103)
```

If the source column is a string column (`char`/`varchar`/`nchar`/`nvarchar`), and the string representation format of the date is `yyyymmdd`, you can safely cast it to date since `yyyymmdd` will always be interpreted correctly by SQL Server, and then use `convert` just like before:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), CAST(stringRepresentationOfDateAsYYYYMMDD As Date), 103)
```

Note: only ISO8601 formats (yyyymmdd | yyyy-mm-dd) is guaranteed to be interpreted correctly regardless of culture settings to date data type (Bewrae: [There's a bug in the `DateTime` data type with the second format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792766/date-conversion-and-culture-difference-between-date-and-datetime)).

If the source column is an `int`, you first cast to `char`, then to `date`, and finally use `convert`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), CAST(CAST intRepresentationOfDateAsYYYYMMDD as char(8)) As Date), 103)
```

Comment: So the first "convert" returns results so the column must already be a date data type. But format is still YYYMMDD and not required 103 British format of DD/MM/YYY.

Comment: So this worked, but no slashes or dashes that is needed.

Comment: CONVERT(char(10),CAST(right(convert(varchar,invoicedate),2)+substring(convert(VARCHAR,invoicedate),5,2) + left(convert(VARCHAR,invoicedate),4) AS VARCHAR) ,103) AS "Invoice Date"

Comment: Convert with style 103 returns `dd/mm/yyyy` with slashes. 105 returns `dd-mm-yyyy` with dashes. If you've got a different value you did it wrong.