# T-SQL convert string from ddmmyyyy to dd MMM yyyy

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have **string** `20120821` and I need to convert it into `21 AUG 2012` **string** also. What is easy way?

Answer (score 2):

There's a big list of the different outputs that you can find [here](https://lsdbtech.wordpress.com/2015/06/25/sql-server-date-conversion-format-codes/).

But to answer your questions:

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(8) = '20120821';

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), CONVERT(DATE, @date), 113);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @t varchar(50) = '20120821'
select convert(varchar(50),convert(date,@t),113)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to a date using `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(right(ddmmyyyy, 4), substring(ddmmyyyy, 3, 2), left(ddmmyyyy, 2))
```

Then you can convert to a string:

```
select convert(varchar(255), datefromparts(right(ddmmyyyy, 4), substring(ddmmyyyy, 3, 2), left(ddmmyyyy, 2)), 106)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cast` and `convert` like:

```
select convert(varchar, cast('20120821' as datetime), 6)
```

or

```
select convert(varchar, cast('20120821' as datetime), 113)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tough this question already have four answers - none of the existing answers is much more than a code dump - so I figured I would add a little explanation.

String representations of dates are considered notorious because a lot of them are ambiguous - For example, **`02/04/2019`** can be interpreted as either **February 4th 2019** or as **April 2nd 2019**.

It gets worst when you have a two digit year - `01/02/03` can represent so many different dates - including different centuries!

Lucky for you, your source string is in one of the two formats that are guaranteed to always be interpreted correctly by SQL Server when converting to **`Date`** (**but not to `DateTime`!**):
`yyyymmdd` is one and `yyyy-mm-dd` is the other.

Both of these formats are international standard and described in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Please note, however, [that there is a known bug (feature?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792766/date-conversion-and-culture-difference-between-date-and-datetime) in the `DateTime` data type that makes the `yyyy-mm-dd` format culture dependent. This bug does not exists in the new and improved alternative data type called `DateTime2`.

I will not add a code to this answer since it would just be repeating the code from [Jim Jimson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57181813/3094533) or from [apomene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57181861/3094533).

Comment: Glad you mentioned the issues with 'yyyy-mm-dd'. When working with dates one should always use 'yyyymmdd' just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @jimjimson that's correct when working with `DateTime`, but none of the other date and time data type has this problem - so as long as you are not using `DateTime` you're safe with the more human readable format of `yyyy-mm-dd`.