# Dates inserting incorrectly - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Dates are not inserting correctly to table, any explanation / solution?

```
create table test 
( 
    ID bigint,
    MarketOpen datetime
);

insert into test (ID, MarketOpen) 
values (1, 2019-01-19-11-40-00);

select * from test;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=55bb3e86a3059e17346d1d383e993837)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats totally the wrong way to enter a date. SQL Server is treating your current syntax as a calculation e.g. `2019-01-19-11-40-00=1948` and then converting the number `1948` to a `datetime`. You need to use a formatted string e.g.

```
insert into #test (ID, EventId, MarketId, RaceDate, MarketOpen, HorseID)
values 
(1, 123, 153722767, '2019-01-19 11:40:00', '2019-01-18 11:40:00', 34434);
```

Note: As mentioned by seanb its best practice to use a [non-ambiguous format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) when specifying dates and the ISO format (`yyyymmdd`) is probably the best of these.

Comment: Note for generality, you should use '20190110' rather than '2019-01-10'. As @AaronBertrand pointed out to me, 2019-01-10 is not universal e.g., [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f2981f11a52e64f13ef1e3e654f6e07)

Comment: Personally, I prefer the more human-readable version of ISO8601 - `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`, but that's really a personal preference. Note that when using the `DateTime2` data type, you can safely use `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. For more information, read [Shnugo's question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45792766/3094533)