# T-SQL date data type format for SQL Server mm/dd/yy or yy/dd/mm or something else?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I am using this version of SQL Server

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4517790) - 15.0.2070.41 (X64)   Oct 28 2019 19:56:59   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19041: ) (Hypervisor)
```

information about locale setting

```sql
select @@LANGUAGE;
-- result: us_english
```

I read reference document

[image]

(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

I have

```sql
DECLARE @date DATE = '12/10/05';
DECLARE @datetime DATETIME = @date;

SELECT @date AS '@date', @datetime AS '@datetime';
```

[image]

As reference document point out, I think it is `mm/[yy]yy/dd` (`12/10/05`; December 5th, 1910), but it return *December 10th, 2005*.

Is reference document wrong? How to easy-to-understand these format? How to understand and remember?

Comment: The reference document also allows for `mm/dd/yy` which is undoubtedly how your default dateformat is set up. It's always safest to use `CONVERT` to ensure your string dates get parsed as you expect...

Comment: Note `12/10/05` as `mm/yy/dd` would actually be December 5th, 2010. See the [two digit year cutoff option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-two-digit-year-cutoff-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You should read the whole document you are referencing to. 1) It's definitively not 1910 because two digit years below 49 are interpreted as 20xx (unless you configured it otherwise) 2) *"The default date format is determined by the current language setting. You can change the date format by using the SET LANGUAGE and SET DATEFORMAT statements."* (cited from referenced document)

Comment: Furthermore, you should not rely on specific settings of your sql instance, but use unambiguous formats like `yyyy-mm-dd` or use `CONVERT` where you can specify the format yourself

Comment: @Nick I read your second comment, then edited question, it is my mistake.

Comment: Reference docs for SET DATEFORMAT state that for us_english the default format (= order of date parts) is mdy. Add "SET DATEFORMAT myd" to your script to change the behaviour.

Comment: @mweber Which is perfectly consistent with the results OP sees.

Comment: @Nick reply your first comment, I also seen `[m]m/dd/[yy]yy` in reference document, I dont' think it is the same with `mm/dd/yy` and/or higher precedence with `mm/[yy]yy/dd`

Comment: @DoNhuVy sure it is, `[m]m/dd/[yy]yy` matches `mm/dd/yy` as well

Comment: @derpirscher If you're using `DateTime`, don't use `yyyy-mm-dd`, but `yyyymmdd`. The former is culture dependent, while the latter is not.  (on that data type only)

Comment: 20 years after Y2K and still the lesson needs to be repeated. **NEVER** use 2 digit years as input.

Comment: @SMor I wonder if around 9990 they will start talking about the Y1M crisis... I Imagine some great-great-great.....great-grandchild sitting on some future version of the internet  complaining about these dumb computer geeks that had 10000 years to prepare for this :-)

Answer (score 1):

First thing is first - [None of the Date/Time data types is stored with the display format in SQL Server.](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)
Second, you've executed `select @@LANGUAGE;` and got back `us_english` - go on and run

```
SELECT dateformat 
FROM sys.syslanguages
WHERE [Name] = @@LANGUAGE;
```

And you'll see the result of `mdy` - which means that the formats for string representations of date values is one of the following:

- `[m]m/dd/[yy]yy`
- `[m]m-dd-[yy]yy`
- `[m]m.dd.[yy]yy`

Third, you should be aware of the fact that when dealing with SQL Server, the language settings are related to the default language of the login, which means different logins might have different language seetings, and of course, it is possible to change the [language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and / or the [date format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) settings - which leads to the conclusion -

You should never rely on language settings for date/time string representations. Instead, use one of formats specified in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), since these are the only two formats guaranteed to be interpreted correctly to a valid date/time value, regardless of the language and dateformat settings, and regardless of the actual data type, [Even `DateTime`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45792766/3094533) And that's juse One reason [why you should never use `DateTime` again](https://hockeygeekgirl.com/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/)).