# Issue with getting date to sort correctly

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I built a program and noticed that in 2018 the sorting is not correct. I fixed it so it would show 2018 first but it still having an issues sorting correctly now it is showing example 1/02/2018 then 1/03/218 and so on, but I need it to show 1/03/2018 then 1/2/2018 then all of 2017 after. Here is my partial code for the model if anymore code is needed I will add it.

Model.php

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class visitor_log_model extends CI_Model {

        var $table = 'visitor_log_list';
        var $column = array('date','name','vendor','department','contact_person','expected_arrival_time'); //set column field database for order and search
        var $order = array('id' => 'desc'); // default order 

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }
    //gets the gets all the records from the database

        private function _get_datatables_query()
        {

            $this->db->from($this->table);
            $this->db->order_by("date", "asc");
            $this->db->order_by("expected_arrival_time", "asc");


            $i = 0;

            foreach ($this->column as $item) // loop column 
            {
                if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
                {

                    if($i===0) // first loop
                    {
                        $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND. 
                        $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                    }

                    if(count($this->column) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                        $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
                }
                $column[$i] = $item; // set column array variable to order processing
                $i++;
            }
```

Comment: Are those "date" columns c really date types?  If not, they should be; you'd get this for free.

Comment: it is a sql server Microsoft with codeigniter

Comment: I just check the database it is setup as navchar I had it that way because I am using a date picker does it matter if I need to change to date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a very bad idea to store a date as a string! Clumsy, slow and erronous...

For SQL Server's engine a string is a string. You can name the column `date` and you can store values, that look like a date, but sorting them will be done according to the rules of alphanumeric sorting (like in a lexicon).

Furthermore: A date format like `1/02/2018` is culture dependant. Some systems will take this as first of Feb, others as second of Jan. This might work perfectly for you and pass all internal tests, but breaks on a customer's machine with silly errors.

1. Store any value with the appropriate type! Use `DATETIME2` or `DATE` with a modern SQL-Server!
2. If you have to use a string format (like in serialisation) you should stick to secure formats! Best is `ISO8601`, which is in most cases `YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` (beware of the `T` in the middle).
3. Think about a date's format (its visual representation) only in your presentation layer!

Comment: so should I change it to date the only issue is I am using a datepicker and it puts the date in a certain way

Comment: Yes! You should store the value as a date type! Your datepicker will either allow to retrieve a typed value or your language will allow to parse a *real* date out of a string. You can change the column to `DATETIME2` or `DATE` and still transfer your data as strings. But use a secure format! [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33230070/5089204) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39504506/5089204)

Comment: You were right I created a new table and changed the type in the column to date and transferred the data over and it works fine now