# Sql Server Table date query showing incorrect result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a Sql server table which contains below Date values(4th october)

[image]

Now Below query is not showing any result

```
  select 
            *
        from [dbo].[TB_AUDIT] TBA 

        where   TBA.ActionDate >= '10/01/2018' and TBA.ActionDate <= '10/04/2018' which is not correct.
```

But If I write 
  select 
            *
        from [dbo].[TB_AUDIT] TBA

```
    where   TBA.ActionDate >= '10/01/2018' and TBA.ActionDate <= '10/05/2018' it is returning me all results.
```

What I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is that January 10 or October 1st? If you ask for dates between January and April, you won't get results from October.  Don't use localized strings. The only unambiguous *date* format is `YYYYMMDD`. The unambiguous datetime format is the full ISO8601, ie `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss….`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *two* problems with this query. The first, is that it's using a localized string. To me, it looks like it's asking for rows between January and April. The unambiguous *date* format is `YYYYMMDD`. `YYYY-MM-DD` by itself may not work in SQL server as it's still affected by the language. The ODBC date literal, `{d'YYYY-MM-DD'}` also works unambiguously.

Second, the date parameters have no time which defaults to `00:00`. The stored dates though have a time element which means they are outside the search range, even if the date parameter was recognized.

The query should change to :

```
select 
        *
from [dbo].[TB_AUDIT] TBA 
where   
    cast(TBA.ActionDate as date) between '20181001' and '20181004'
```

or

```
    cast(TBA.ActionDate as date) between {d'2018-10-01'} and {d'2018-10-04'}
```

Normally, applying a function to a field prevents the server from using any indexes. SQL Server is smart enough though to convert this to a query that covers the entire date, essentially similar to

```
where   
    TBA.ActionDate >='2018:10:01T00:00' and TBA.ActionDate <'2018-10-05T00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 3):

When you don't specify a time component for a `DATETIME`, SQL Server defaults it to midnight. So in your first query, you're asking for all results `<='2018-10-04T00:00:00.000'`. All of the data points in your table are *greater* than `'2018-10-04T00:00:00.000'`, so nothing is returned.

You want

```
TBA.ActionDate >= '2018-10-01T00:00:00.000' and TBA.ActionDate < '2018-10-05T00:00:00.000'`
```

Comment: That should probably be a [half-open interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology) with the `ActionDate` less-then, but not equal to, the end date + 1. (Based on the apparent intent of the OP's first query.)

Comment: @HABO, absolutely correct. I was lazy and copied & pasted from the question to get the field name and missed modifying the operator. Edited, and thanks for the +1.

Answer (score 1):

Use properly formatted dates!

```
select *
from [dbo].[TB_AUDIT] TBA 
where TBA.ActionDate >= '2018-10-01' and TBA.ActionDate <= '2018-10-04'
```

YYYY-MM-DD isn't just a good idea.  It is the ISO standard for date formats, recognized by most databases.

Comment: In SQL Server even `YYYY-MM-DD` can be affected by the locale.. [This reminded me though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228765/how-do-i-specify-date-literal-when-writing-sql-query-from-sql-server-that-is-lin) that the ODBC date literal also works

Answer (score 0):

when you just filter by the date, it is with regard to the time as per the standard.